# How to find function caller while in strict mode

Tags: javascript, angularjs, strict

I have a function, `getGames()`, in my Angular controller which can be called by both my `init()` function and an `update()` function. I need to know whether `init()` or `update()` called this function because I treat each situation differently.

I tried to access `arguments.callee.caller.toString()`, but this is not allowed while in strict mode, which is a requirement for this project.

How could I access the caller of `getGames()` while in strict mode?

My current structure below. Obviously `loadingGames.promise` within `updateSchedule()` does not work because that promise was already resolved when `init()` ran. I'm struggling to refactor this so that `init()` and `updateSchedule()` each depend on a different promise resolution with regard to the same function, `getGames()`.

```
var loadingGames = $q.defer();

var getGames = function() {
  playersService.getGames({
    playerId: playerId
  }).$promise.then(function(data) {
    vm.games = data;
    loadingGames.resolve();
  });
};

var init = function() {
  getGames();
}

init();

var updateSchedule = function() {
  getGames();
  loadingGames.promise.then(function() {
    populateOptions(vm.games);
    vm.tableParams.reload();
  });
};
```

My thought was to determine the `caller` at the end of `getGames()` then resolve a different promise based on who the caller was.

Comment: This sounds a lot like you should rethink your design. A function that needs to know who called it to behave correctly is not really a good function. Maybe it should just be two different functions that maybe internally share a third function that they use for their similiar logic?

Comment: This function is a member of a `$q.all` array with regard to its relation to the `init()` funciton. There are about a half dozen async operations that need to complete before my `init()` function can finish. However, once the page is loaded a user can take certain actions which only require `getGames()` to be resolved before the view is updated. What I'm aiming to do is resolve different promises based on whether `init()` was the caller or `update()` was.

Comment: That still sounds like you are trying to do two different things in one function. As your asynchronous operations return promises, where is the problem of exposing/deriving the ones that you want to fork special behaviour on? Just because something waits for a lot of promises, that does not mean that something else can not wait for only one of them

Comment: @LionC, added details to my original question. That is my current structure and better highlights my aims and, obvious, current error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `getGames()`-function could return a promise that is resolved as soon as the games have been fetched from the server(to make my example code shorter I left out the parameter to the service and assumed that it returns a promise):

```
var games; //This is vm.games in your case

(function fetchGames() {
    games = playersService.getGames()
        .then(function(data){
            games = data;
            return data;
        });
})();

function getGames() {
    return $q.when(games);
}

function updateSchedule() {
    getGames()
        .then(function(theGames){
            populateOptions(theGames);
            tableParams.reload();
        });
}
```

[`$q.when(x)`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#when) returns a promise that is immediately resolved with `x` if `x` is not a promise. If `x` is a promise, it returns `x` directly.

Just a note: Your `populateOptions` and `tableParam.reload` functions look a lot like you do manual DOM-stuff. This is almost always wrong in angular - let data binding do that job for you.